# Rails render command responding api wrongly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncable

I have an API method that's implemented just like this:

```
  def change_status_operacao

    if @user.change_status_operacao(params[:status], params[:empilhadeira_id].to_i, params[:motivo_id].to_i)
      emp = ModeloEmpilhadeira.find(params[:empilhadeira_id].to_i)
      ActionCable.server.broadcast "filas", {fila: "aguardando", object_dom: render(partial: "application/operacao_detalhe", locals:{ empilhadeira: emp})}

      render json: { message: I18n.t("app.change_status_success") }, status: 200
    else
      render json: { errors: I18n.t("app.change_status_error") }, status: 400
    end

  end
```

The problem is, when I'm doing  `render(partial: "application/operacao_detalhe", locals:{ empilhadeira: emp})` for rendering a html content for my action cable channel, it seems to be responding my api call with that content, instead of the render right bellow, with 200 code. If I take out that broadcast, it works correctly, but I need to pass that html rendered to my channel. So how can I call that render method so it doesn't respond to the api call?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `render` only once in a method. When you call `render` to generate the partial, that partial will be used as response.

Try `render_to_string` to send the partial through the channel.

Comment: Got it, but render_to_string is getting the same result for me. Isn't there another wai to get the html content as a string for a partial?